# Conditional in zsh scripting - comparing strings

Tags: string, scripting, conditional-statements, zsh

Currently I'm learning about shell scripting in zsh but I have the next issue. I am tryng to compare an input string to an specific character ("A" in this case). Here is my code.

```
#!/bin/zsh
# Author: Cristhian Rodriguez
# Conditional statement

OPTION=""
read OPTION\?"Input an option (A or B): "

if [[ $OPTION -eq "A" ]]; then
  echo "Correct answer!!"
else
  echo "Wrong answer!!"
fi
```

When I input some values, look at the outputs:

```
Input an option (A or B): A // Correct answer!!
Input an option (A or B): B // Wrong answer!!
Input an option (A or B): C // Correct answer!!
Input an option (A or B): f // Correct answer!!
```

The point is: when I type a different value from A or B, the output is always `Correct answer!!`, but the program should return `Wrong answer!!`. Could you tell me if I am wrong in the code.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Please remove the line numbers; they make it annoying to copy & paste your code.

Comment: `-eq` is used to compare by numeric value...

Comment: @Shawn Sure, I removed numbers. So, in that case is better to use == ?

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: @Shawn Yeah, it worked. Another question is, when should I use ( ), [ ], (( )) and [[ ]]?

Comment: The comparision should be `[[ $OPTION == A ]]`.

Comment: BTW, you can find this information in _man zshmisc_, in the chapter _CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS_.